# Zookeeper vs kafka raft

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, raft

Why ZooKeeper was replaced with kafka-raft for metadata management in Apache kafka ?

I went through the articles on apache's blog ( [apache.org](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum) ) as well, but couldn't find exact and concise reasons.

Looking forward to some good insights.

Comment: What would you suggest it is replaced with instead? Do you want to manage Zookeeper cluster **and** Kafka, or just Kafka?

Comment: I am not suggesting something to replace zookeeper with. I am just trying to figure, what was the reason to deprecate zookeeper and choose kafka raft instead ?

Comment: Primarily because it'll make Kafka easier to install, compared to other products like NATS, RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc that don't require external resources

Answer (score 4):

From the Kafka Improvement Proposal (KIP) document:

> Currently, Kafka uses ZooKeeper to store its metadata about partitions and brokers, and to elect a broker to be the Kafka Controller.  We would like to remove this dependency on ZooKeeper.  This will enable us to manage metadata in a more scalable and robust way, enabling support for more partitions.  It will also simplify the deployment and configuration of Kafka.

Read more here: [KIP-500: Replace ZooKeeper with a Self-Managed Metadata Quorum](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum#KIP500:ReplaceZooKeeperwithaSelfManagedMetadataQuorum-Motivation)